# How to add materialize to angular 2 project?

Tags: angularjs, angular2-template, angular-material2

I am moving from  angular 1.5 to angular 2 for this project while setting up new app i came to this issue so i am adding this library to app. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize but this one throws error this library is not compatible. I want to use angular materialize that supports angular 2. Any better source or how to implement using above library.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StreamComponent } from './stream/stream.component';
import { StreamService } from './stream.service';
import { routing } from './app.routes';
import { MaterializeModule } from "angular2-materialize";
const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'app',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'stream',
    component: StreamComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StreamComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    MaterializeModule
  ],
  providers: [StreamService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ERROR

```
angular-material.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
    at angular-material.js:13
    at angular-material.js:14
    at angular-material.js:36390
(anonymous) @ angular-material.js:13
(anonymous) @ angular-material.js:14
(anonymous) @ angular-material.js:36390
index.js:4 Uncaught ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Couldn't find Materialize object on window. It is created by the materialize-css library. Ple…, …}
```

Answer (score 0):

To import materialize you need to add import statement in your code

```
import { MaterializeModule } from "angular2-materialize";
```

and after declare it in imports

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  //...
    MaterializeModule,
  ],
  //...
})
```

I guess in your case problem with import, try to declare MaterializeModule before routing. If it does not help pls provide error message

Comment: i tried adding material module before routing still same issue i have added error in question.

Comment: i dont see materialize.css under dist directory

Comment: Are you install angular2-materialize in your local directory or global?

Comment: i install into project that is local